# GridFieldManager Blackberry align fields

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a GridFieldManager whith 3 columns and I want to align their content like this:

```
    |Title left | Title Center | Title Right|
```

The problem is that I'm using a RichTextField instead of a LabelField because I want the text of each title to grap like this:

```
    |Title left | Title Center   | Title Right  |
    |is wrapped | is wrapped too | also wrapped |
```

If I use RichTextField instead of LabelField, then, the the alignment is ignored. This is my code:

```
public class CustomGridFieldextends GridFieldManager {

    private int numColumns = 3;
    private int margin = 5;

    public CustomGridField(String leftText, String centerText, String rightText) {  
        super(1, 3, GridFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        setPadding(0, margin, 0, margin);

        int columnWidth = (Display.getWidth() / numColumns);
        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
            setColumnProperty(i, GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE, columnWidth);
        }

        // leftmost text
        RichTextField leftLabel = new RichTextField(leftText){
            protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.setFont(getFont().derive(Font.BOLD));
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        leftLabel.setFont(getFont().derive(Font.BOLD));
        add(leftLabel, Field.FIELD_LEFT);

        // center text
        RichTextField centerLabel = new RichTextField(centerText){
            protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setFont(getFont().derive(Font.BOLD));
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        centerLabel.setFont(getFont().derive(Font.BOLD));
        add(centerLabel, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);


        // rightmost text
        RichTextField rightLabel = new RichTextField(rightText) {
            protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setFont(getFont().derive(Font.BOLD));
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        rightLabel.setFont(getFont().derive(Font.BOLD));
        add(rightLabel, Field.FIELD_RIGHT);
    } 

    protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
        // draw a nice background...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, turns out that I had to use this styles when creating the RichTextFields:

```
new RichTextField("text on left",RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
new RichTextField("text on center",RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_HCENTER);
new RichTextField("text on right",RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

Now I'm working on the grapping...

PD: found it here: http://v4ks1n.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/richtextfield-alignment/